# Indexing issue in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008, clustered-index

hey guys, 
i have a query in sql server which takes atleast 10-15 seconds to execute, and when this is called in asp.net, it is more worst there, it just throws request timeout error.

Below is the query i am using.

```
SELECT C.Id,
       C.Summary,
       C.Title,
       C.Author,
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), C.PublishDate, 104)
       AS 'DATE',
'/Article/' + SUBSTRING(dbo.RemoveSpecialChars(C.Title), 0, 10) + '/' + CAST(CA.CategoryId AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + '/' + CAST(C.Id AS VARCHAR(MAX)) +
'.aspx' AS
'URL'
FROM   CrossArticle_Article C
       INNER JOIN CrossArticle_ArticleToCategory CA
         ON C.Id = CA.ArticleId
WHERE  C.Title LIKE '%' + @KEYWORD + '%'
        OR C.Summary LIKE '%' + @KEYWORD + '%'
        OR C.Article LIKE '%' + @KEYWORD + '%'  


    SELECT @@ROWCOUNT
```

Below are the Fields Specification.

```
Id int Primary Key
Summary nvarchar(1000)
Title nvarchar(200)
Author nvarchar(200)
PublishDate DateTime
CategoryId int PrimaryKey
```

i think this can be resolved by using Indexing on these columns using include.. i checked over net, but didnt find any solution..

i would appreciate if i could get help for the same.
Thanks and Regards
Abbas Electricwala

Comment: You would need to look into full text indexing for this. You are doing a leading wildcard search on the 3 widest columns on your table so a clustered index scan is the only sensible plan/indexing for this query. How many rows are in `CrossArticle_Article`?

Comment: @Martin: there are around 22000 records in crossarticle_article. can you also tell me how can i use fulltext index to resolve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ordinary column indexing most likely cannot help your query, unfortunately. `LIKE` conditions can only be assisted by indexes when they are in the form of `value%` (meaning that you can only have a wildcard on the *end* of the expression; the prefix must be static).

I am assuming that you already have an index on `CrossArticle_Article.Id` and `CrossArticle_ArticleToCategory.ArticleId`. If not, you should add those.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yes i do have primary key index on both those fields, and also if i use wildcard just at the end of the expression how can i make the performance better..

Comment: @Abbas: If you only have a wildcard at the end of the expression, then adding an index on `Title`, `Summary`, and `Article` should help.